# To every Markov process corresponds a Q-matrix?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Logarithm of a Markov Matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31174/logarithm-of-a-markov-matrix)

It is known that to every Q-matrix corresponds a unique Markov process. Does the converse hold? Specifically,

1. Can a (discrete state, continuous time) Markov process not be differentiable at the origin, i.e. can
   $$\lim_{t\downarrow0}\frac{1}{t}\mathrm{P}_e[X_t=d]\space\space(*)$$
   not exist for some states $e,d$?
2. If $(*)$ exists for all $e,d$, letting $q(e,d)$ denotes this limit, can $q$ fail to exhibit either of the following two properties?

   i) $q(e,d)\geq0$ for all $e,d$,

   ii) $q(e,e)=-\sum_{e\neq d}q(e,d)$
3. If $(*)$ exists and both $(i)$ and $(ii)$ hold, can the following condition still fail?

   iii) $\sup_{e\in E}|q(e,e)|<\infty$
4. Does a time-inhomogeneous Markov process have a Q-matrix? If so, is it unique?