# Markov Chains : Can anything be said about what happens in between two transition?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

In time homogeneous discrete Markov chains we take a set period for a single transition. In examples we see sometimes depending on the examples the transition period being a a month a week etc. I'm wondering whether anything can be said on what happens during a transition (for example if a transition period is one month what happens after 2 weeks?) or if it is possible to reduce the transition period of the existing model which may in some cases help to improve the predictions. I do not know whether this is a valid question to ask regarding MCs, however I believe it is an interesting question that I should share here. I welcome any answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ denote the transition matrix of some discrete Markov chain $(X_n)$ indexed by the nonnegative integers. Assume that $P=\mathrm e^Q$ where $Q$ is the generator of a Markov process $(\xi_t)$ indexed by the nonnegative real numbers, then it is natural to realize $(X_n)$ using $(\xi_t)$, by the identity $$X_n=\xi_n,$$ valid for every integer $n$. In other words, one *embeds* the discrete time process $(X_n)$ into the continuous time process $(\xi_t)$ in the sense that $X_0=\xi_0$ and that $(\xi_t)$ realizes a Markov interpolation between the successive states $X_0$, $X_1$, $X_2$, etc. The transition kernel of this interpolating process during a time interval of length $t$ is $\mathrm e^{tQ}$, for any nonnegative $t$.

The limitations of this approach are twofold:

- Not every transition matrix is $P=\mathrm e^Q$ for some generator $Q$ (those that are are called *embeddable*).
- Some transition matrices are $P=\mathrm e^Q$ for more than one generator $Q$.

Comment: Thanks. I have never come across anything like this. Under what sort of topics can I find this theory in a Markov chain book? Can you suggest some reading material if possible?

Comment: For starters, you could try [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/31184/6179).

Comment: Here is what I understood, correct me if I am wrong. $e^{tQ}$ gives a whole set of Markov chains which explains transitions which could happen in between the transition time of the original matrix. So if we start of with a transition period of 10 days and try to find out what may happen after 5 days we simply find the matrix corresponding to $e^{5Q}$ which would give the transition probabilities for a 5 day period between the states. Hope this is right

Comment: Roughly yes. If $P=e^Q$ corresponds to 10 days, the matrix transition for 5 days would be $e^{Q/2}$.

Comment: Thanks but why do we have $e^{tQ}$ then? I'm assuming you did not get $e^{Q/2}$ simply by assigning $t=1/2$

Comment: ?? Obviously I DID get $e^{Q/2}$ by choosing $t=1/2$ in $e^{tQ}$... Please explain your trouble MUCH more clearly.

Comment: So $t∈[0,1]$ irrespective of the length of the time interval?

Comment: No. If $P=e^Q$ corresponds to 10 days then the transition matrix for 42 days would be $\exp(4.2\cdot Q)$.

Comment: thanks it makes more sense now

Comment: How so? I just repeated the exact thing I had said from the start.

Comment: The example you gave helped me grasp the concept better. Not saying your answer lacked anything.

Comment: No problem, teaching is a mysterious thing anyway.